# finding unique element Id within occurences of same class in CSS for Sharepoint online

Tags: css, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to have different hover colours on each of the items in the top nav bar in Sharepoint online but they are the same CSS class and I can't work out what to put in the CSS to differentiate between the different ocurrences. currently i have:

```
.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li.static > .ms-core-listMenu-item:hover {
border-top-width: 0;
border-right-width: 0;
border-left-width: 0;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
border-color: #571757;
```

which colours them all the same...
the Sharepoint site said this was offtopic there and sent me here

Comment: Youcan try with nth-child option

Comment: thanks. do you have a link with more info on that?

Comment: Added example code in the answer and posted link as well.

Comment: Fantastic, I was having trouble working out where the Nthchild element went in with the rest of the elements. I had found that link but applying it to the code I have is challenging

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example which you want. for more info you can go here https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/

```css
li:nth-child(1):hover{
color:red;
}
li:nth-child(2):hover{
color:blue;
}
li:nth-child(3):hover{
color:pink;
}
li:nth-child(4):hover{
color:gray;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: 'code'
    .ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li.static > .ms-core-listMenu-      item:hover {
 border-top-width: 0;
 border-right-width: 0;
 border-left-width: 0;
 border-bottom-width: 3px;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 border-color: green;
}
.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li.static > .ms-core-listMenu-item:nthchild(2):hover {
{
 border-top-width: 0;
 border-right-width: 0;
 border-left-width: 0;
 border-bottom-width: 2px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 border-color: red;
 is that the right syntax?

Comment: @Hydrogen `.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li.static:nth-child(2) > .ms-core-listMenu- item:hover` is the right syntax, You missed `-` , further if you can show me the html it will be more clear

Comment: Ah yes sorry. Silly mistake. However even with the - in place its not working. You are right it must be in the HTML rather than the CSS.

Comment: @Hydrogen `.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li.static:nth-child(2) > .ms-core-listMenu- item:hover` this will work

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I have. something must be wrong elsewhere then:-) thanks

Comment: Got this working by embeding that section of code directly on the page. thanks for your help